# error 502 bad gateway when download file angular 11?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-components, angular11

I work on download `zip file` from `angular 11` .

I face issue when download Large files but small files not have any issue .

Large file i download have `size 2.397 kb.`

it will take 7 minutes to finish download but after 2 minute give me error 502 bad gateway.

it download file from local pc without any issue but when try to download file from remote server publish give me `error 502 bad gateway` .

so How to solve this issue and why I get this error ?

```
e {headers: n, status: 502, statusText: 'Bad Gateway', url: 'https://pn.xxx.com:7072/api/Z2Delivery/ExportNxp', ok: false, …}
error: Blob
size: 1477
type: "text/html"
[[Prototype]]: Blob
headers: n
lazyInit: ƒ ()
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {size: 0}
[[Prototype]]: Object
message: "Http failure response for https://pn.xxx.com:7072/api/Z2Delivery/ExportNxp: 502 Bad Gateway"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 502
statusText: "Bad Gateway"
url: "https://pn.xxx.com:7072/api/Z2Delivery/ExportNxp"
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: ƒ e(e)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

what i have tried

```
web api
[Route("ExportNxp")]
        public IActionResult ExportNxp(bool areIdentical)
        {
         
                if (areIdentical == false)
                {
                    return OK("Not Matched Excel");
                }
                else  
                {
                   
                return PhysicalFile(zipPath, "application/zip", Path.GetFileName(zipPath));
              
                }

        }
service.ts
PostUploadzipNxp(file:any):Observable<any>
{
  formData.append('file', file,file.name);
  return this.http.post('https://pn.xxx.com:7072/api/Z2Delivery/ExportNxp/', formData,{observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' });
}
component.ts
 this._dataService.PostUploadzipNxp(this.fileToUpload)
     .subscribe(blob => {
       saveAs(blob.body, this.fileToUpload?.name +'.zip');
      });
```

Comment: thank you for reply are this supported also on .net core 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET Core request time out is 2 minutes, and you can change it via KeepAliveTimeout in program.cs file

in .net core 6.0

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(t =>
{
  t.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
});
```

in .net core 3.1

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
 }

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureKestrel(o => { o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout =  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); });
```